# After switching default shell, .command file just opens terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command, fish

I have a myscript.command file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash


rm -rf ~/Downloads/*
```

that I added to the login items. However, when I login or manually execute it via double click, it just opens a terminal with my default fish shell without removing any file. If I set my default shell back to zsh, it works.

Why is that? What can I do?

What I've tried so far:

- Change shebang to zsh, sh, fish
- Make file executable for all users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: Instead of switching the default shell like described in the [official guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/change-the-default-shell-trml113/mac) (lol) you can switch it by using

`chsh -s /path/to/shell`.

For some reason this makes .command files work again. Just make sure your desired shell is listed in `/etc/shells`